# how can i get the id of a item or a menu in typoscript?

Tags: html, typo3, typoscript

I have three different menus in TypoScript. If I click one item from any of them, I want this menu was shown on the next page (template), showing one item or another according to the element clicked.

I only need to do this:

(lib.menu_right < lib.menu1)  or  (lib.menu_right < lib.menu2)  or  (lib.menu_right < lib.menu3)

But i don`t know how get the current clicked page.

EDITED: My menu1 structure is:

```
## Menu 1 [Begin]
lib.menu1 = HMENU

lib.menu1.special = list
lib.menu1.special.value = 6933, 6918, 6917, 6916, 6915


lib.menu1.1 = TMENU


lib.menu1 = HMENU
lib.menu1.entryLevel = 0
lib.menu1.wrap = <ul class="lista_sin_estilo margen_top_medio tam_bloque1>|</ul>
lib.menu1.1 = TMENU
lib.menu1.1.NO {
  allWrap = <li class="lista_primero">| <hr class="linea_separadora"></li>
}

lib.menu1.1.ACT = 1
lib.menu1.1.ACT {
  allWrap = <li class="lista_primero">|<hr class="linea_separadora"></li>
}
## Menu 1 [End]
```

Comment: Remove special = list and use entryLevel? Can you explain what you have and what you want to get? IMHO a different way could be easier...

Comment: I have 3 menus in the same page. When I click in one of the menus, the next page show the content of this page and its menu at the right (menu_right). Maybe there is a easier way to do that, do you know how?

I have the same code with differents ids for lib.menu2 and lib.menu3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with conditions like

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id = 1] || [globalVar = TSFE:id = 2] # if current page has uid 1 or 2
lib.menu_right < lib.menu1
[global]
[globalVar = TSFE:id = 3] || [globalVar = TSFE:id = 4]
lib.menu_right < lib.menu2
[global]
```

if you know the uid's of all pages. If your pages in the menu are organised in respective subpages, then you may look for the rootline like

```
[PIDupinRootline = 1] # if current page is inside rootline of page uid 1
lib.menu_right < lib.menu1
[global]
```

Comment: If you don't want to work with the uids and have a clean page tree, then you may also be able to use the `treeLevel` instead.

Comment: I have try this but it didn't work. Let me edit the question and add the Menu1 structure, similar to all the menus.

Comment: @jerogaren as far as I understand your edit, your menu includes just predefined uid's. In this case go with my first example. By the way, are you sure you will keep your menu with fixed uid's? It's easier to handle if you create navigation trees with shortcuts (see my example in http://pastebin.com/2ngpJsqE)

Comment: @Viktor Dick I have tried your last example, but i can't change que menu becouse this and all the menus are shown in the main page. When I click in one of the menus, the next page show the content of this page and its menu at the right (menu_right). And yes, i will keep my menu with fixed uid becouse i can't find other way to have 3 differents menus in the same page and add any page in the menus that i want.

Comment: Ok, Finally your first option works!! When i tested it the first time, didn't work, maybe some problem with cache. I saved me two days trying to fix this problem in my web. Thank you very much! I would like you see my web when it was uploaded on produccion.